# Firebase trigger on all collection items while only one has been updated

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, triggers

Every time I do an update with the same object(s3) with same values and properties, Firebase trigger the event 'child_added' even if there's nothing to add or update.
I made some test by modifying on the firebase console some values in subcollection of the main object and noticed that it returns a snapshot with the first element correct and then all the other elements of the collections as 'ADDED' elements. This is not true because the collections didn't change except the one on which I performed an action.

I just need that when I send the same identical object that is stored on the db, firebase will recognize smartly that no action is requested and no trigger need to be activated.

```
 var studentiRef = ref.child('studenti/' + s3.matricola);
    studentiRef.update(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(s3)));

    studentiRef.on("child_changed", function(userSnapshot) {
      var tasseRef = userSnapshot.ref.child('tasse');
        tasseRef.on('child_added', function(itemSnapshot, prevKey){
          console.log('ADDED ON');
          console.log(itemSnapshot.key)
        })
    });

    studentiRef.on("child_changed", function(userSnapshot) {
        userSnapshot.ref.child('tasse').on('child_removed', function(itemSnapshot, prevKey){
          console.log('REMOVED ON');
          console.log(itemSnapshot.key)
        })
    });

    studentiRef.on("child_changed", function(userSnapshot) {
        userSnapshot.ref.child('tasse').on('child_changed', function(itemSnapshot, prevKey){
          console.log('CHANGED ON');
          console.log(itemSnapshot.key)
        })
    });
```

UPDATE:

Before posting update I made some experiments with no successful results.
Here the pics of the console, the database and the code.
Going nuts on this.
Here three screenshot: 1 [firebase data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1oJX.png) 2 [snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeM6u.png) 3 [console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFycZ.png)

UPDATE II:
[scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPDeM.png)

[behaviours on modifying value in firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3yJZ.png)

SOLVED:
By getting inspired from the github firebase examples, I found out a common mistake in using firebase: i was not flatting the data.
To continue using my data structure (a root object within a list of objects), the solution was to trigger an update of every single object (pseudocode: ref.update(root/childobject) n-times instead of ref.update(root).
If someone else ran into this problem, I will explain better.
Always, FLAT YOUR DATA! (using firebase)

Comment: Please paste snapshot of firebase console and show which object you are updating it seems you are updating root object and then running the `child_changed` event on the child of root so if you wants to get only updated value get reference to child of `studentiRef` and update the same

Comment: I attached three screenshots

Answer (score 1):

Most likely these events come directly from the client SDK, which doesn't detect if there was an actual change. The database server *does* perform such a check, and will only send out changes to other clients if there was an actual change.

Update:

The Firebase client + server behave in the following way when you're calling telling it to update a node to its current value.

1. The client fires the local event(s) to reflect the update. So `child_changed` will fire.
2. The client send the update to the server. This is needed since the client and server may be (slightly) out of sync, and the server is the single-source-of-truth.
3. The server compares the update with the current value of the node. If it is the same, the process stops here.
4. If the updated value is different from the current value and passes validation/permission checks, the data is committed to disk and broadcast to any active listeners.
5. If the updates value is different, but rejected by the validation/permission checks, the servers sends a rejection message to the original client, which then fires another `child_changed` event to revert the local change.

Comment: I just attached three screenshot

Comment: I'm not sure how to read the data+code. Can you try reproducing it in a site like jsbin? The local window should trigger `child_*` events for all data, but if you open a second window it should only show if there was an actual change.

Comment: Thanks for helping. For the completeness of the scenario: there are two nodejs applications. One perform refTasse.update everytime it runs. The 95% of the times it is going to update with the same objects and no changes, so I hope firebase will not trigger any events. The other nodejs application stands listening on firebase events, there's no frontend. Only server side. I just attached a new screenshot, hoping to be more clear as possible on UPDATE II line in the original post

Comment: I update my answer to describe how the system behaves, which is probably more useful in your situation.